# Hashids: Compatibility between swift and C version

Tags: java, c, swift, hashids

I am using Hashids swift version to encode an array and I am using C version to decode it with same SALT. The decoding is successful only one time after reset, and after that every time decoding fails. The C version is  1.1.3 and Swift version is 1.1.0. Though I am not facing this issue if encoding is done using the Java version of Hashids on Android. Java version is 1.0.1.

The C code is:

```
size_t decode_hashids(const char *salt, char *hash, unsigned long long num_array[])
{
  hashids_t *hashids;
  hashids = hashids_init3(salt, MIN_HASH_STRLEN,HASHIDS_DEFAULT_ALPHABET);
  size_t bytes_decoded = hashids_decode(hashids, hash, num_array);   
  hashids_free(hashids);
  return bytes_decoded;
}
```

The Swift Code is:

```
let hashIds = Hashids(salt: salt , minHashLength: 6)
let id = hashIds.encode(number, number)
```

For all versions I am using the latest updated version on respective Hashids GitHub repository.

Edit: this is the github repo https://github.com/tzvetkoff/hashids.c, this link is provided on hashids website: http://hashids.org/c/

The call to hashids_init3 or any other function does not modify its value. In fact salt is a string in both languages. So in C its const char[] type and in Swift its String type. The value of salt is kept as a hardcoded value in both languages which does not change for the device (i.e. an arm based processor) where C code is running.

Comment: exactly which gethub repository?  what is the value and definition of `salt`?  does the call to Hashids() or `hashids_init3()` modify the contents of `salt`?   What is the current state of that project? I.E. does the project work correctly for all languages, both encrypting and decrypting?

Comment: Please see edit. Also the current state of the project should be stable I guess. They have not mentioned issues for any language on their website. I see quite some people using hashids for php, javascript and all those languages. I don't exactly get what your question is.